# xml editor in vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, editor, text-editor

i have to create a xml editor in vb.net.. i have to validate xml code if there is a error in the syntax it should be displayed in a another textbox.. validation should be done while typing the xml code itself.. the error should be while typing xml coding in  run time application . i should get the syntax while typing the xml code in run time itself

Comment: Posting your customer's requirements without showing any progress from your part will unlikely get you answers.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these samples of XML editors found online; you might find some ideas to help get you started:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/XMLEditor.aspx
- http://mycodelog.com/2010/04/01/xml-editor/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/dlxmleditor/
- http://gregsxmleditor.codeplex.com/